Fitting the function with appropriate parameters
I am trying to fit the following data  with the function f[d, c, tc, t] := d*Exp[-c/Sqrt[t - tc]];
 data={{0, 1}, {5, 0.755357}, {10, 0.589732}, {15, 0.444643}, {20, 0.330804}, {25, 0.228571}, {30, 0.169196}, {35, 0.147768}, {42,  0.00223214}}

as
 f[d_, c_, tc_, t_] := d*Exp[-c/Sqrt[Abs[t - tc]]];
 model = f[d, c, tc, t];
 result = FindFit[data, model, {{d, .4}, {c, 1.0}, {tc, 60.0}}, t]
 p2 = Plot[model /. result, {t, 0.0, 70}, PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
 Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]

Which gives the desired plot

but I have problem with the fitting parameter {d -> 12411.7, c -> 94.8046, tc -> 100.837}
I am expecting the parameter to be small, It is possible to get so ?

You can always try to constrain the values of the parameters, like so: NonlinearModelFit[data,  {f[d, c, tc, t], 0 <= d < 1000, 0 <= c < 10, 0 <= tc < 1000}  , {{d, .4}, {c, 1.0}, {tc, 60.0}}, t, MaxIterations -> 10000]. Using NonlinearModelFit is also nice, because it computes things like confidence intervals as well. If you do result = NonlinearModelFit[data,    f[d, c, tc, t], {{d, .4}, {c, 1.0}, {tc, 60.0}}, t,    MaxIterations -> 10000]; result["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"] you'll see that the confidence intervals are gigantic.

You should have mentioned that you got an error message:  FindFit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.  Although including ``MaxIterations -> 5000gets you{d -> 27282.6, c -> 106.006, tc -> 107.468}`.

Is the first data point '{0,1}` really a data point that was measured?

@JimB, it is calculated data

I'm asking would the first data point {0,1} for all possible samples would always be {0,1} and not, say {0, 0.998}.  If so, then that's analogous to forcing a regression through the origin which corresponds to setting the intercept to zero.

Fitting $e^{-d x}$ (where there is just a single parameter) gives almost as good a fit.  But is there some theoretical reason for the model you propose?

@JimB, Yes, theoretical reason, do you have any suggestion for a function similar to exp(-x) but it should cut the x-axis at some point?

Your model contains more complexity than what the data capable of in terms of estimating the parameters.  However, you are able to make predictions that might very well meet your needs.
I would NonlinearModelFit and avoid using FindFit as FindFit doesn't have any capability of providing fit diagnostics.
Running NonlinearModelFit results in the following parameter estimates:
result = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {{d, .4}, {c, 1.0}, {tc, 60.0}}, t, MaxIterations -> 500];
result["ParameterTable"]


Looking at the parameter correlation matrix we see that the correlations among the parameters are nearly 1 which indicates an overparameterized model given the available data.
result["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm


So it is hopeless to have any confidence in the estimates of the parameters but within the range of the data you might have adequate predictions.
